# How can i access the vps server

Tags: ssh, cpanel, whm

Have a VPS and access to WHM as cpanel.But how can i access the php.ini and also connect using SSH.With SSH getting error

```
Failed to connect to server:
    Network error: Connection refused.
```

If there is a proxy that is blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better asked at [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com). Having said that, by default in common Linux distributions (Ubuntu, for example), SSHD is not running by default.

Verify that you are running an SSH server, and if you are still having issues, this is better taken somewhere more relevant.